# I have reference ID and i have to display it dynamically but its not working!

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Here is the code that i written:

```
<script> 
function myFunction(var num) 
{ 
 alert("Claim form has been successfully created with reference number:" + num); 
} 

<apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" oncomplete="myFunction({!Case.Claim_Reference__c});"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your console? Your oncomplete should be this at the very least: oncomplete="myFunction('{!Case.Claim_Reference__c}');"

Comment: Are you using `StandardController` or a custom controller? Can you post the code?

Comment: When writing JavaScript you need to check your browser's console which is where JavaScript errors are reported. In Chrome this is Tools -> Developer Tools -> Console. You can even paste your function in the console and see an error.

Comment: I am using standard controller.

Comment: I have some javascript errors and it always points to the myfunction line in script

Comment: Unfortunately i am not using Chrome. I am using IE8 because that is the requirement.

Comment: please do update your question with the javascript error you are getting. One thing that does popup when I look at your code is that your script tag is not terminated. (but could be copy paste issue?)

Comment: @VishweshPrabhakar Most browsers have JavaScript debug facilities - you need to just find out how they work. (Or also have e.g. Chrome available when something goes wrong.) One problem is that instead of "var num" you should just have "num".

Comment: i have terminated the script tag just copy paste error and the java script error that i always get is expected identifier missing

Comment: @VishweshPrabhakar This site isn't a discussion forum and its focus is not JavaScript syntax so at this point I think you should work on this on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Add single quote when you call your field. Also if you set your Clain_Reference__c into your submit method, you will need to reRend your button or the section.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" oncomplete="myFunction('{!Case.Claim_Reference__c}');"/>
```